# Index out of bound when storing data from database as an array in List view?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Hello im trying to store data from my database as an array and then i will be using it for myadapter to create a customised list view, however i got index out of bound for this.

Here is my code to retrieve data from my database to store it as an array (Main activity)

```
int[] avatarImage = {R.mipmap.blademaster,R.mipmap.gunslinger,R.mipmap.pyro}; 
//i didnt store my image to my database because i dont know how to store and retrieve it so i use manual array

List<Avatar>values = db.getAllAvatars();
        int countOfValues = values.size();
        String[] titles = new String[countOfValues];

        for (int i=0; i<=countOfValues; i++) {
            titles[i] = (String)values.get(i).getName();
        }

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.avatarlv);

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,titles,avatarImage);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

My Adapter java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    String [] names;
    int [] avatarImage;
    Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context,String[] nama,int[] aImage) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_main);
        this.names = nama;
        this.avatarImage = aImage;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return names.length;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_main, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.mAvatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        }
        else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        mViewHolder.mAvatar.setImageResource(avatarImage[position]);
        mViewHolder.mName.setText(names[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView mAvatar;
        TextView mName;
    }

}
```

but when i run it "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gorila.sqlite_grid_view/com.example.gorila.AvatarShop.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4"

Please Help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your this.avatarImage you have only 3 elements, but in getView your try to get like this `mViewHolder.mAvatar.setImageResource(avatarImage[position]);` if the position is 4 it will give IndexOutOfBoundsException.

For testing just comment that line and run, It will work fine.

or you can do like this,

mViewHolder.mAvatar.setImageResource(avatarImage[(position % avatarImage.length)]);

Answer (score 0):

You have a <= in for loop

`for (int i=0; i<=countOfValues; i++)`
it should be

```
for (int i=0; i<countOfValues; i++)
```